# can't compile my old projects (with gcc)

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake, yocto, clion

I have a broken C Compiler when I use `CLion` with `yocto SDK`, but it works fine on `eclipse Oxygen`. 
This is the error in the compiler:

```
    CMake Error at /home/developer/yocto_SDK2/toolchain2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:51 (message):
      The C compiler
      "/home/developer/yocto_SDK2/toolchain2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc"
      is not able to compile a simple test program.
```

And this is the log error:

```
/home/developer/yocto_SDK2/toolchain2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.4.0/real-ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/home/developer/yocto_SDK2/toolchain2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.4.0/real-ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/home/developer/yocto_SDK2/toolchain2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.4.0/real-ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
/home/developer/yocto_SDK2/toolchain2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.4.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc
/home/developer/yocto_SDK2/toolchain2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.4.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/home/developer/yocto_SDK2/toolchain2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.4.0/real-ld: cannot find -lc
/home/developer/yocto_SDK2/toolchain2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.4.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc
/home/developer/yocto_SDK2/toolchain2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.4.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/home/developer/yocto_SDK2/toolchain2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.4.0/real-ld: cannot find crtend.o: No such file or directory
/home/developer/yocto_SDK2/toolchain2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.4.0/real-ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
```

I have also configured the paths manually, and it was fine. 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem for the gcc compiler ?

Comment: Can you compile from the command line?

Comment: Your compiler belongs to a sysroot, but you need to tell it. It is possible yocto dumped a CMake toolchain definition file (extension .cmake) somewhere under `.../toolchain2/sysroots`, in which case you can point CMake to it using `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=...`

Comment: @PaulSanders it compiles fine in the Command Line, but when I tried to build project in Clion, the gcc compiler shows that error.

Comment: @Botje I already added the Cmake to the directory, look at the screenshot I just added. but still, it doesn't work. It gives me the same error

Comment: Does the CMake log show which command it tried?

Comment: @Botje It shows this in the log: `Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "
CMakeFiles/cmTC_69520.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_69520'
  failed` `cmTC_69520/fast"` and `make[1]: *** [cmTC_69520] Error 1`

Comment: Does that `build.make` still exist and does it contain an invocation of your compiler?

Comment: You could do what we did and *retire* `Yocto` for the much simpler `Buildroot` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after researching, trying and failing all the possible options, I found my answer which is the following:
Apparently **Clion** can't detect the Compilers unless I `source` and `cmake` before launching **Clion**, so it could redirect the Compilers to **Yocto** compilers rather than detecting the host Compilers.
So, I created the following *Bash* script which launches the mentioned commands.

Sourcing *setup_sdk* as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# define root paths
export SDK_TC_ROOT=~/yocto_sdk/toolchain
# source yocto sdk stuff
source ${SDK_TC_ROOT}/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
```

Then, I ran the following *bash* code to make sure that the setup runs correctly before launching **Clion**

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH_TO_Clion=~/clion/bin
# setup env
source setup_sdk
cmake ./
# start Clion with all variables
$PATH_TO_Clion/clion.sh
```

Then Clion auto-detected the Compilers correctly without defining them manually which resulted to the mentioned **C Compiler** Issue.

It is worth to mention that **Clion** somehow doesn't accept the `-` parameter when defining **Cmake Options** in `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`. As it compiled and build correctly for me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
My case a bit more complex though. I need to switch between default tool-chain (x86) and yocto cross-compile toolchain (ARM) to compile the same project.

I come up with the following solution:

1. Create a bash script which calls the script initializing Yocto env and then call cmake:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/yocto_sdk/toolchain/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi; bash -c "cmake $(printf ' %q' "$@")" C
```

2. Create a new toolchain with the script set as CMake.

[image]

3. Then you can switch between the default and the yocto tool-chains while working.